# C Recursive Function for Compounding Interest

Tags: c

I have a project where I have to calculate compounding interest. Given a user inputed period, I have to take that period and subtract it from one until the `period = 0`.

```
double interest(double initialDeposit, double regularDeposit, double percent, int period, double total) {

    total = ((1 + percent) * (period)) + regularDeposit;

    if (period > 0){
        return period - 1;
    }

    else {
        return total;
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to write a recursive function with the period decreasing by one until it equals zero?

Comment: Is the exercise to write a recursive function, or to calculate compound interest?

Comment: I added more to the code. Does that help more?

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the required variables to your interest function. In order to compute the compounded interest recursively<sup>**[1]**</sup>, you will need to pass:

- `principal` (your `initialDeposit`) which is the base sum to which the
- `deposit` (your `regularDeposit`) is added; before
- multiplying by the interest `rate` (your `percent`) divided by
- the number of annual compounding periods `cmpperiod`; all done
- for the total number of periods `nperiods`

This can be implemented recursively with the following:

```
double interest (double principal, double deposit, double rate, 
                    int cmpperiod, int nperiods)
{
    principal += deposit;
    principal += principal * rate / (double) cmpperiod;
    nperiods -= 1;

    if (nperiods == 0)
        return principal;
    else
        return interest (principal, deposit, rate, cmpperiod, nperiods);
}
```

(**note:** the number of annual compounding periods and total number of periods have been changed to type `int` to avoid issues inherent in floating-point equality comparison due to the inability to represent all values exactly -- for all real-world financial code implementations dealing with money, floating-point calculations should be avoided for that reason and exact types used)

**footnotes:**

1. Avoid using recursive functions where a simple procedural loop will suffice. Each recursive call is a separate function call requiring a separate function stack. While there are some factorials and permutations where the recursive solution is more elegant, those are the exceptions and not the rule.